# Mocking http requests in node using mocha and sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, http, mocha.js, sinon

I have written a NodeJS app using express that proxies some calls to external APIs. So I am trying to write a unit test using Mocha and Sinon. My goal is to test the app without any internet connectivity so I am trying to mock the https requests and return mock replies.

I'm having a problem that I can't find any examples or tutorials that fit my case. My node app listens on port 8081 for http requests and then proxies them to another site. I want to test my app without it having to actually send the request to those external servers. I'm trying it below and I put the json replies I want to send back in the server.respondsWith() function.

Am I doing this the right way by making an ajax call with chai? or should I be sending the requests inside my app somehow. Any help is appreciated.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var chai = require('chai');
var spies = require('chai-spies');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var https = require('https');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');

chai.use(spies);
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Car Repository', function() {
  var server;
  before(function() {
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  });

  after(function() {
    server.restore();
  });

  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081';
  it('should succeed and return a list of cars', function(done) {
    server.respondWith('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.cars.com/v2/token_endpoint', JSON.stringify({"access_token":"1t3E4IykfpJAbuFsdfM2oFAo5raB5vhfOV0hAYe","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":604800}));
    server.respondWith('GET', url+'/cars', JSON.stringify({'test':'this works'}));

    chai.request(url)
      .get('/cars')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.have.property('test');
        console.log(res.body);

        done();
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out the [Nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) library. It does exactly what you're looking for.

> Nock is an HTTP mocking and expectations library for Node.js
>
> Nock can be used to test modules that perform HTTP requests in isolation.
>
> For instance, if a module performs HTTP requests to a CouchDB server or makes HTTP requests to the Amazon API, you can test that module in isolation.

Comment: wow man nock looks really great and their documentation is perfect. I'll spend some time trying it out now

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

The new solution here is sinon's fake server:

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/fake-xhr-and-server/#fake-server

Comment: This is a dead link since 2018..
Here's an updated link:
https://sinonjs.org/releases/v15/fake-xhr-and-server/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [node-tdd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tdd) and the `useNock` flag. It builds on top of mocha and nock (mentioned in the accepted answer) and automatically creates and uses a recording file for each test.

We love that it's so easy to use. Basically just "enable and forget" and focus on writing requests / test cases. If requests for a test change, one still needs to delete or adjust the recording file, but at least it's entirely separate from the code.