# Class method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, node-request

I am writing a class in JavaScript that sends HTTP requests for a specific URL. I'm trying to test that class with Mocha but for some reason, the method fetchUrl() returns `undefined`. I can't seem to figure out why. I literally started writing in JavaScript a day ago, therefore I am still trying to learn and adjust to it.

```js
 fetchUrl () {
    var request = require('request')
    var res
    request(this.url, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error) // Print the error if one occurred
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('received status code other than 200 OK')
        this.error = true
      }
      res = response
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode) // Print the response status code if a response was received
      // console.log('body:', body) // Print the HTML for the requested url.
      this.html = body
    })
    return res
  }
```

```js
describe('Test Http request to google.com', function () {
  it('should return 200', function (done) {
    assert.equal(httpCon.fetchUrl().statusCode, 200)
    done()
  })
})
```

Comment: `fetchURL` is returning undefined because `res` is not defined before return statement and you are expecting definition inside your async code.

Comment: Or possibly better [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) libray to mocking HTTP request.

```
const axios = require('axios');
module.exports = {
   getUser(username) {
     return axios
        .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
};
```

**And here test case:**

```
describe('Get User tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
       nock('https://api.github.com')
         .get('/users/octocat')
         .reply(200, response);
    });
});
```

For more details, you can look at this: [mocking-http](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-tests-mocking-http-requests) also look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441395/mocking-http-requests-in-node-using-mocha-and-sinon) answer of SO. [source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-tests-mocking-http-requests)

Answer (score -3):

I think you should only return res inside the callback, otherwise it will return undefined since the program keeps running...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function
You may want to take a look on callback funcionality

Comment: it still returns undefined, i think because the method becomes type void